# Handling url rewrites and static files with Kraken JS

Tags: node.js, express, url-rewriting, kraken.js

I have a one page app which I'm converting from a more traditional Apache setup to KrakenJS. It all goes really well except for one bit.

The app uses sockets to change its state, and we used to generate friendly URLs for our users to get back to a previous search. Using a .htaccess setup like so :

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon\.ico|favicon\.png|media|robots\.txt|crossdomain\.xml|css|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

That way, our static files were handled properly, and all the rest was redirected to index.php which handled the parsing and went on to query the right results (eg : example.com/section1/category1, would redirect to the main page, and send a query through the socket for section1,category1 items.

I've tried modifying my main route in index.js to add a wildcard, but it fails to handle the static files (`RewriteCond $1 !^(*static extensions*)` )

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
   ...
}
```

This one works fine for the use case where the user starts at the frontpage, but (obviously) gives me non-existing routes if I want to access directly /sec1/cat1

```
router.get('*', function (req, res) {
   ...
}
```

This one redirects correctly, but cannot find the static files.

Any idea how to handle the static files in a similar fashion than the RewriteCond does?